# Xml feed Parser for image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xml, xcode

In my app, I used XML feed parser to get all the contents. But I got the **null Array for Images**  which are included in parser.

My code for parsing is as follow:

```
#pragma mark MWFeedParserDelegate

- (void)feedParserDidStart:(MWFeedParser *)parser {

    NSLog(@"Started Parsing: %@", parser.url);

}

- (void)feedParser:(MWFeedParser *)parser didParseFeedItem:(MWFeedItem *)item {
    NSLog(@"Parsed Feed Item: “%@”", item.title);


    if (item) 
    {

 [arr_itemIdentifier addObject:item.identifier];
        [arr_itemTitle addObject:[item.title gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML]];
        [arr_itemLink addObject:item.link];
        [arr_itemdate addObject:item.date];




        if( nil != item.updated )
        {
        [arr_itemupdated addObject:item.updated];
        }
        [arr_itemsummery addObject:item.summary];
        NSString *renderedSummary = [item.summary stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:@"<[^>]*?>"
                                                                           withString:@""];
        [arr_itemRenderedSummary addObject:renderedSummary];
        if( nil != item.content )
        {
            [arr_itemContent addObject:item.content];
        }

    }


    NSLog(@"%@",item.description);
    NSLog(@"item.enclosurs = %@",item.enclosures); // here i got null array so the for loop is not executed
    for( NSDictionary *itemEnclosure in item.enclosures )
    {
        NSString *mimeType = [itemEnclosure objectForKey:@"type"];
        if( [@"video/example" isEqualToString:mimeType] )
        {

        } else if( [@"image/example" isEqualToString:mimeType] )
        {
            NSString *itemAnchor = [itemEnclosure objectForKey:@"url"];
            NSArray *captures = [itemAnchor arrayOfCaptureComponentsMatchedByRegex:DWFeedHTMLImageElementSrcValueRegex];
            if( 0 < captures )
            {
                [arr_imageURL addObject:[itemEnclosure objectForKey:@"url"]];
            }
            [arr_thumbImage addObject:[itemEnclosure objectForKey:@"url"]];

            //feedItem.thumbnailURL = feedItem.imageURL;

        } 

    }

    int k=0;

    NSLog(@"arr_itemContent = %@",item.content);
    NSLog(@"arr_itemdate = %@",item.date);
    NSLog(@"arr_itemIdentifier = %@",item.identifier);
    NSLog(@"arr_itemLink = %@",item.link);
    NSLog(@"arr_itemRenderedSummary = %@",[arr_itemRenderedSummary objectAtIndex:k]);
    NSLog(@"arr_itemsummery = %@",item.summary);
    NSLog(@"arr_itemTitle = %@",item.title);
    NSLog(@"arr_itemupdated = %@",item.updated);

    k++;
}







- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:str_url];
    feedParser = [[MWFeedParser alloc] initWithFeedURL:feedURL];
    feedParser.delegate = self;
    feedParser.feedParseType = ParseTypeFull; // Parse feed info and all items
    feedParser.connectionType = ConnectionTypeAsynchronously;
    [feedParser parse];

}
```

I got all the array information except images. I also get image url with content like: `<p><a href="http://wpcore.mpf.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/DDD-2121.jpg">` CONTENTS

through log output by `item.content`

Comment: show us the xml used.. some thing might be missing der..

Comment: the xml might be 'wrong' not have 'url' or you dont alloc arr_thumbImage

Comment: if my url is wrong ,then how can i get all other info & i alloc arr-thumbimage

Comment: show us the xml and your log output.

Comment: xml url is http://feeds.feedburner.com/MakePartsFast & log output is for item.enclosures is null